# Checkmark appearing on every cell upon loading app

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I load my app I see all cells have a checkmark. I want it to be unchecked to start with.

Does anyone know why this is happening from the code below? (It's the only section of the view controller that has the checkmark accessory mentioned.)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        } else {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
}
```

Comment: Set the default state in Interface Builder. By the way, calling `tableView.cellForRow(at` twice is unnecessarily expensive. And be aware that changing the state in `didSelectRowAt` is not persistent and can cause unexpected behavior on scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below code. You need to set the default accessoryType in cell for Row and then on didSelectRow you can change as per your logic. I have created a simple Model to show how you can set the default accessoryType on reload

```
import UIKit

struct CellInfo{
    var title:String
    var isSelected:Bool
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTV: UITableView!

var CellInfoArr = [
    CellInfo(title: "First Row", isSelected: false),
    CellInfo(title: "Second Row", isSelected: false),
    CellInfo(title: "Third Row", isSelected: false),
    CellInfo(title: "Fourth Row", isSelected: false),
    CellInfo(title: "Fifth Row", isSelected: false)
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    myTV.delegate = self
    myTV.dataSource = self
    myTV.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return CellInfoArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = CellInfoArr[indexPath.row].title
    if CellInfoArr[indexPath.row].isSelected == true{
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        CellInfoArr[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
    } else {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        CellInfoArr[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
    }
}
}
```